# Would it be good C++ style to mimic the C# / D difference between struct / class?

Tags: c++, class, coding-style, struct, d

If my understanding is correct, the following semantics apply to structs and classes in C++, C# and D:

```
        struct          class
----------------------------------
C++     stack/heap      stack/heap
        value/reference value/reference

C# / D  stack           heap
        value           reference
```

I.e., in C++ there is no semantic difference between structs and classes (apart from the default public / private access). In contrast, C# and D structs have value semantics and stack allocation (at least by default), whereas C# and D classes have reference semantics and heap allocation.

**My question is: would it be good C++ style to mimic this difference by using the struct keyword exclusively for all entities with value semantics, and the class keyword exclusively for all entities with reference semantics?**

It would of course be a self-discipline tool not enforced by the compiler, but it could improve code readibility, especially for reviewers with C# / D backgrounds. OTOH, the current idiom in C++ seems to be to only use the struct keyword for simple entities such as pure POD aggregates and template metafunctions only, so it could be confusing for C++ programmers.

Comment: This is subjective (and therefore not really appropriate for SO).  But the answer is almost certainly: no.  It's not a good idea to mimic the idioms and semantics of one language with an entirely different language.  The translation is not (and cannot be) robust, so can only lead to confusion.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: why would it not be robust? It'd simply be an annotation to indicate intent that is familair to users of other languages.

Comment: One reason is that, as you've already said, there's no language-level enforcement.  Secondly, this won't accurately represent the semantics of C# (e.g. memory ownership vs. garbage collection), which is likely to lead to programming errors down the line (specifically memory-related errors, which are notoriously hard to debug).

Comment: You start mimicking class/struct semantics and you end up passing parameters by reference. No!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: stack-allocated structs are automatically cleaned up, and by always using shared_ptr or unique_ptr for classes that are heap-allocated (which is a good practice anyway), the GC point seems moot, right?

Comment: @Daniel Daranas: passing class parameters by reference is precisely what you want (to avoid slicing)! And why would passing large structs by reference be bad?

Comment: @rhalbersma: That was a half-joke. "The C/C++ technique for passing parameters is always the same, regardless of calling convention: All parameters are passed by value, except for arrays, which are translated into the address of the first member. To pass data by reference, pass a pointer to it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that were the only relevant distinction, it might make sense.  In
practice, there's much more to it than that.  In C++, it's very frequent
for objects with real behavior (and which don't support copy) to be
allocated on the stack; it also occurs from time to time that pure data
containers be allocated dynamically.  C# and D are confounding two
orthogonal distinctions: arbitrary object lifetime vs. object lifetime
linked to scope, and whether the object has value semantics or not.
While it's true that these two distinctions do coincide for some types,
it's not an absolute rule, and imposing it at a language level creates a
straight jacket which at times prevents the use of the cleanest and most
natural solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really helpful and constructive answer.

Comment: D only makes the distinction between value type semantics and reference type semantics when it comes to `struct` vs `class`, you can still put structs on the heap and classes on the stack. It is not "confounding" (did you mean "conflating"?) the two like you falsely claim.

Comment: You can't allocate a class on the stack explicitly in @safe code (though the compiler may be able to do so in some cases) because a dangling reference could occur.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ a struct and a class is basically same other than a class having primarily private members and a struct has defualtly public members. They have no impact as to where the memory is allocated.

While this is a matter of taste, it is common in C++ to use structs for value object to group together values and use classes for fully featured constructs that fully implement value semantics (assignment operators, constructor...).

To place either a class or a struct in dynamic memory you should use the new operator and have a pointer to the onbject.

```
 my_object *mop=new my_object();
```

or tie it life tie to a reference count or scope with smart pointers .

```
 std::unique_ptr<my_object> mop(new my_object());
```

or with reference counting

```
 std::shared_ptr<my_object> mop(new my_object());
```

You should always try and use the stack for most items and let container hold large data structures.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the familiar mechanics of stack / heap allocation. My proposal is to clarify such intent by the use of the struct / class keywords. Simply put, any entity not meant as a base class, would be declared as a struct, and the rest as a class.